# Value of rbp changing after jumping into a new function

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, att, red-zone

I have the following assembly program:

```
.globl main
main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    movb $8, -1(%rbp)
    movw $30, -4(%rbp)
    mov -1(%rbp), %rax
    add -4(%rbp), %rax
    call func
    pop %rbp
    ret

func:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    movl $7, -4(%rbp)
    mov -4(%rbp), %rbx
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

When stepping through the program, after the `call func` but before the `push %rbp` when trying access the value of `rbp`, which was previously $0x0800001e` (8 byte, 0 byte, 0 byte, 30 byte), it now shows all zeros:

```
>>> x/1xw $rbp-4
0x7fffffffe410: 0x00000000
```

Why does this occur? Does `rbp` reset its value (though keeping its address) between function calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value *of* RBP doesn't change.  Each asm instruction only changes the architectural state of the machine (register + memory contents) in the ways documented in the manual.  (Intel and AMD both publish PDF manuals; HTML extract of the instruction-set reference from IInel's PDF at https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/)

You're dumping memory pointed-to by RBP, not printing the value of RBP.  (Do that with `p /x $rbp`.  Or use GDB's TUI mode with `layout reg`.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for GDB tips).

**The memory changes when [`call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) pushes a return address**.  You didn't reserve any space for your local vars with `sub $8, %rsp` for example, so RSP = RBP and the space below RSP is where `push` and `call` write.

That's why non-leaf functions can't use the red-zone (below RSP) for their local vars.